# the different settling speed of two solid particles in fluid

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, drag, buoyancy

In a container full of fluid A, which can be water or oil, I have two solid particles, both of which are of the same material. These two particles are of different size. One is bigger than the other one. I observed that the bigger one settled faster than the small one in the fluid. How to explain this phenomenon?

Comment: [Terminal velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) most probably.

Answer (score 1):

If the particles are small you can assume laminar flow and use [Stoke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) to estimate the drag force $\|F_\text{drag}\| \propto \mu R w$ as a function of viscosity $\mu$, radius $R$, and fall speed $w$. The gravitational force in terms of $R$, gravity $g$, and the particle density $\rho$ is given by $\|F_\text{grav}\|\propto g\rho R^3$ setting the two equal gives 
$$w\propto \frac{g\rho R^2}{\mu} $$
as the particles grow their decent rate increases.